Is there evidence that Kurt Gödel took his proof of the existence of God to be conclusive?
Kurt Gödel, usually regarded by academics as probably the greatest logician of the 20th century (although not by me), produced a formal proof that the existence of God is a logical necessity.
Do we know whether Gödel was serious? Is there evidence that he took his proof to be conclusive?
(Disclosure: I take any proof that the existence of God is a logical necessity as inevitably illogical.)
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

See Kurt Gödel (Solomon Feferman & John Dawson & Warren Goldfarb etc editors), Collected Works: Volume III: Unpublished essays and lectures (1995, Oxford UP), Introductory note to Ontological proof (1970), page 388:

in 1970 he [Gödel] told Oskar Mongestern that though he was "satisfied" with the proof, he hesitated to publish it, for fear it would be thought "that he actually believes in God, whereas he is only engaged in a logical investigation (that is, in showing that such a proof with classical assumptions [completeness, etc.], correspondingly axiomatized, is possible)." [From O.Morgenstern diary].

Wrt the question:

Is there evidence that he took his proof to be conclusive?

According to the previous quote, Gödel's inestigation was aimed at showing that the proof is formally valid i.e. that the conclusion follows from the premise.
If so, the proof is "logical"; but in order to be "conclusive", i.e. demonstrating the "existence", this depends on the assumptions: no proof without assumptions.

Oh, the irony, if Gödel believed his own proof...

You may follow the link Goedel's ontological proof. It says and gives further references:

In August 1970, Gödel told Oskar Morgenstern that he was "satisfied"
with the proof, but Morgenstern recorded in his diary entry for 29
August 1970, that Gödel would not publish because he was afraid that
others might think "that he actually believes in God, whereas he is
only engaged in a logical investigation (that is, in showing that such
a proof with classical assumptions (completeness, etc.)
correspondingly axiomatized, is possible)."

Accordingly Goedel's proof was not a joke but an excercise in logic.
